# Preferred Choices and Visual Separator in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm struggling with this in Symfony 2.

I have a combobox with optgroups, and I need to have a pre-selected choice. This works if I use the example from the [Symfony Offical Site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html).

```
    $builder->add('foo_choices', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array('foo' => 'Foo', 'bar' => 'Bar', 'baz' => 'Baz'),
        'preferred_choices' => array('baz' => 'Baz'),
    ));
```

But the problem is that, the pre-selected choice appears separated from the rest by "------------" and the label of the otpgroup also repeats itself. Something like this.

```
optgroup label_1
    opt_1
-----------------
optgroup label_1
    opt_2
    opt_3
 optgroup label_2
    opt_4
```

I Know I can change the visual separator, but what I really need is 1 option pre-selected, using 'choices', without all that visual effects.

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code like this should be selecting Bar by default, so you don't need modifications on that.

You can remove the separator when rendering your input in the twig template like:

```
{{ form_widget(form.foo_choices, {'separator':none}) }}
```